# Using recycled bitmap ... on live wallpaper

Tags: android

I have a silly bug I can't seem to get rid of... It happens predictably.

I am using a bitmap that I recycle when the surface is destroyed on my lwp... To prevent memory overuse when rotating the lwp.

But if I open the settings window, then rotate that window to landscape, then rotate it back to portrait view and press back to close the setting window (to go back to the lwp), I get a crash due to trying to use the recycled bitmap... On the LWP draw procedure.

What is going on?

Is there a proc. I can call to define the bitmaps again after closing the settings window to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use a bitmap once you recycle it so clear the pointer to it after you recycle it and check that it isn't null before you draw it

if it is null then load it again

Comment: Thank, I knew I had to do this but couldn't pin point where ...  It turns out that 'onSurfaceChanged' is to place to check if the bitmaps null or not.